# Model property is filled with another property of similar name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My model is as follows:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Email address:")]
public string Email { get; set; }
public string ExternalIdEmail { get; set; }
```

In my view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
```

On entry to the view, I double checked, and confirmed that @Model.Email is an **empty string**, but the input textbox is always rendered with a default value of that of ExternalIdEmail !

My action is:

```
public ActionResult action(string email)
{
    return View(new actionlModel() { ExternalIdEmail = email, Email = "" });
}
```

It looks like `m.Email` is taking the value contained in the action parameter `email`.  If I changed it to:

```
    public ActionResult action(string emailX) { ...
```

then it works properly.

Is this by design?

Comment: You explicitly give your `ExternalIdEmail` the `email` value, and you set `Email` to an empty string. Why does it surprise you that `Model.Email` is empty?

Comment: Not surprised, but confirming that it is indeed empty.  But the textbox in @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.`Email`) is showing the value of `ExternalIdEmail` and not the empty string in `Email`!

Comment: Are you sure about that? Edit your post with the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design:

The Html helper methods are preferring to use the `ModelState` over the actual model values. You can read more about this here: [ASP.NET MVC Postbacks and HtmlHelper Controls ignoring Model Changes](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Apr/20/ASPNET-MVC-Postbacks-and-HtmlHelper-Controls-ignoring-Model-Changes)

Because the `ModelState` gets filled with the different value providers (Form fields, Route data, QueryString etc.) in your action the `ModelState` will contain a value for the `email` property and this get used when calling `Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)`

For fixing this (beside renaming your parameter as you've already noticed) you just need to clear the `ModelState`.

If you don't want to "resuse" anything just call `Clear()`

```
public ActionResult action(string email)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View(new actionlModel() { ExternalIdEmail = email, Email = "" });
}
```

Or you can clear by its values for a single property calling `Remove`:

```
public ActionResult action(string email)
{
    ModelState.Remove("email");
    return View(new actionlModel() { ExternalIdEmail = email, Email = "" });
}
```